# my python code show last day of previous month instead of current month

Tags: python

This is my python code:

```
import datetime
import jdatetime

jcurrent_year = jdatetime.datetime.now().year
jcurrent_month = jdatetime.datetime.now().month
jcurrent_day = jdatetime.datetime.now().day
jnow = jdatetime.datetime.now()
jlast_day_of_current_month = jdatetime.date(jnow.year, 1 if jnow.month==12 else jnow.month, 1) - jdatetime.timedelta(days=1)

dcurrent_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
dcurrent_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
dcurrent_day = datetime.datetime.now().day
dnow = datetime.datetime.now()
dlast_day_of_current_month = datetime.date(dnow.year, 1 if dnow.month==12 else dnow.month, 1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

I use `jdatetime` for Jalali date format, but to make sure if something's wrong with this module, I used `datetime` but it's wrong too.

I googled and saw different answers on Stackoverflow and other websites, but they're either using modules rather than `datetime`, or they're showing last month's last day.

I'm not sure what's wrong with this code, but I'm going to dynamically find the last day of current month in Jalali date.

The date in Jalali is now 13th day of 11th month, the year is 1402 and this month has 30 days.

As you see, the `dlast_day_of_current_month` shows the 31st of January, instead of 29th of February.

```
>>> jlast_day_of_current_month
jdatetime.date(1402, 10, 30)
>>> dlast_day_of_current_month
datetime.date(2024, 1, 31)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from jdatetime import datetime, timedelta

current_date = datetime.now()

# Calculate the next month and handle year change
next_month = 1 if current_date.month == 12 else current_date.month + 1
next_year = current_date.year + 1 if current_date.month == 12 else current_date.year

first_day_of_next_month = current_date.replace(day=1, month=next_month, year=next_year)

# Subtract one day to get the last day of the current month
last_day_of_month = first_day_of_next_month - timedelta(days=1)

print("Last day of the month:", last_day_of_month)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, but the output of both is `(jdatetime.date(1402, 10, 30), datetime.date(2024, 1, 31))`, which is not correct. Would you please check again?

Comment: I edited the code, you can find the first day of next month, then substract one to find last day of the current month.
Output of this code is: Last day of the month: 1402-11-30 11:04:33.651171

Comment: Thanks, but what about the next month which is 12? The `current_date.month + 1` if month is 12, then I'll have this error: `ValueError: month must be in 1..12`. Should I add some `if`s if `month == 12` and then add +1 to year and then change the month to 1?

Comment: you're right but that shouldn't be a problem. I edited it again.